# php file_get_contents, location redirection

Tags: php, redirect, location, file-get-contents

I use the sme_block script for IP blocking on my website. The script takes the IP list from block_this.txt. However, this only works if block_this.txt is in the same directory. How to make php files from other directories access block_this.txt? Because uploading the same block_this.txt to every directory is too time consuming, list is updated often and website has many directories. Same problem with redirecting for blocked IPs (location:).

```
function smeblock($a)
{
    $temps=file_get_contents("block_this.txt");
    
    $cts = explode("|", $temps);
    foreach ($cts as $ctsc)
      {
    $ctsc = trim($ctsc);
    $word = preg_quote($ctsc, '#');
    $pattern = "#$word#i"; 
    if ( preg_match($pattern, $a) )
      {
    header('Location:https://www.google.com');    die();
      }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the absolute path to blocklist, e.g.

```
function smeblock($a)
{
    $temps = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/block_this.txt");
//...
}
```

or define the path as a global constant:

```
const PATH_TO_BLOCKLIST = '/var/www/html/block_this.txt';
function smeblock($a)
{
    $temps = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_BLOCKLIST);
//...
}
```

Comment: oh, it looks it is really doing something.. Big thanks, clearly there's some hope. What about 'location'? Would like to have blocked IP redirected too..

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem with the blocked IPs is. Your function gets the content of "block_this.txt" and processes it. Maybe you could update your example by adding some example lines of block_this.txt and an example function call of smeblock()

Comment: example lines of block_this.txt are: 12.23.04.123|12.23.04.122|12.23.04.124|12.23.04.125| etc. with no other code. This goes in php file: smeblock($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);smeblock($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);smeblock($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); Final result of the script is to redirect to some page in this case it is google.com.